# Paypal payments pro integration in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, credit-card

I would like to integrate the Paypal payments pro for my rails 3. I have set the api credentials from sandbox business account form paypal developer account.

Here my problem is I can able to credit the amount for my product checkout. But unable to view the payment transaction details in the sandbox account.

I need to use paypal payments pro using dodirectpayment paypal method.

Can anyone please provide any examples or let me know the issue why the amount is not debiting in the sandbox account

Thanks

Comment: So you're making a successful call but it's simply not showing up in the account like it should..??  If so, it sounds to me like maybe you have your credentials mixed up and the account you're signing into isn't actually the account that you got the credentials from.

Comment: I successfully created two accounts one is for business account and the other is personal account. I am using the business account api credentials in my application. And testing the credit card details with personal account i created. I can able see the funding amount that is been credited into the business account . But when i signin with the personal account the transaction details is not crediting there..

Comment: I've never experienced that, so it doesn't make sense to me, but anything is possible.  Setup a basic button on a page for that same business account in the sandbox and send me a link to it.  I'll buy from it using my sandbox buyer account and see if it shows up on my end.

Comment: Hello sam, I am getting the same issue at my end...Can you please help me? Did you get any solution regarding this?